# Customise Sharepoint Online Navigation

Tags: sharepoint-online, navigation, modern-experience, communication-site

I would like to pile up the current set of sub-sites  "May be using a Ribbon or Editing the Current Navigation " instead of us  using the ... dots and then navigating to the sub-sites, using the Drop Down. Not sure if there is a way to do that.

Any Help will be appreciated.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

If you have lot of navigation links, ellipses (...) will be shown as per the screen size (due to responsiveness). I don't think you can avoid this on SharePoint online site.

So, try to use the combination of menu & submenu for navigation in SharePoint online.

If you want to show multiple submenu/subsite links, you can use **Megamenu** navigation style which will look like below (on hover of main menu link, no additional click needed):

[image]

You can change navigation style from **Change the look settings**, [Change the look of your SharePoint site](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/change-the-look-of-your-sharepoint-site-06bbadc3-6b04-4a60-9d14-894f6a170818).

**Reference**: [Customize the navigation on your SharePoint site](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/customize-the-navigation-on-your-sharepoint-site-3cd61ae7-a9ed-4e1e-bf6d-4655f0bf25ca)